# Clear caches in login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, caching

I have an asp.net login page. For the safety, I want to clear caches. But I don't know where should I put the code.

Thanks for code snippet advice.

```
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        bool UserAuthenticated = false;
        MembershipProvider AuthenticationProviderUsed = null;
        RoleProvider roleProvider = Roles.Providers["SqlRoleProvider"];
        // Try authenticating the user against each membership provider
        foreach (MembershipProvider membershipProvider in Membership.Providers)
        {
            try
            {
               ...
                 Page.Session.Add("workspriv", access_value);
            }
          if (UserAuthenticated)
          {
            Response.Redirect("~/Search.aspx");
          }
  }     

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblDisclaimerText.Text = AntiXss.HtmlEncode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DisclaimerText"]);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Action"] != null && Request.QueryString["Action"].ToLower() == "logout")
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What caches do you want to clear?  Everything in `Cache`? The output cache?

Comment: where is the cache here?

Comment: Maybe it is a wrong question. I just worry user's login information was stored in caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just worry user's login information was stored in caches

It is not.  If a user can re-establish a session again after leaving the page, it's because they still have a session cookie from a previous visit.

Having said that, if you still want to clear caches:

To clear cache memory, you can do this:

```
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())

{

    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(enumerator.Key);

}
```

to clear the output cache:

```
HttpRuntime.Close();
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/archive/2008/08/11/how-to-remove-all-items-from-cache-memory.aspx

Comment: In Page_Load or Login1_Authenticate?

Comment: Since you want to perform that action when a user logs in, Login1_Authenticate seems like a more appropriate place.  Why do you want to clear the cache?

Comment: Also see my updated answer.  I don't think you want to do this.

Comment: So what is the purpose for clearing caches since everything is safe? I may misunderstand the concepts between caches and cookies.:-)

Comment: The things you are caching may become invalid due to various conditions.  For example, if you cache News Headlines, and you get a feed of new News Headlines every 30 minutes, you want to invalidate (the appropriate part of) the cache when you know that you are updating the underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

Please call it just before this before line bool UserAuthenticated = false; or pageload

```
List<string> cacheList = (from DictionaryEntry cache in HttpRuntime.Cache select cache.Key.ToString()).ToList();
cacheList.ForEach(c => HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(c));
```

Comment: There is no Session_Start event but there is a session in the code.(Just updated code).

Comment: I want to know what is the proper place to add the code for clearing caches.